# Как изменить цвет background если подключен svg?

Tags: css, svg

Как изменить цвет background, если BG выступает svg, не меняя цвета самого svg?

```
hicn_1{background: url(../img/img_route_walk.svg) no-repeat top left; background-size: contain; }
```

Comment: может быть поможет `filter:hue-rotate(180deg)`

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы изменить цвет у подключаемого SVG файла, можно использовать `mask-image` свойство **CSS**.

**Данное свойство не имеет поддержки в IE**, но имеет 91% поддержку с префиксом и 6% без.

Поэтому **на текущий момент использовать строго с префиксом**.

Подробнее про поддержку можно узнать [здесь](https://caniuse.com/#search=mask-image)

Ссылка на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7s6vgdr)

Код:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

i.icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-mask-size: contain;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-position: center;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
i.icon.icon-like {
  -webkit-mask-image: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/25/25423.svg");
}
i.icon.color-black {
  background-color: black;
}
i.icon.color-red {
  background-color: red;
}
i.icon.color-green {
  background-color: green;
}
i.icon.color-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<i class="icon icon-like color-black"></i>
<i class="icon icon-like color-red"></i>
<i class="icon icon-like color-green"></i>
<i class="icon icon-like color-blue"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Цвет фона добавляется в конце описания `background`:

```
hicn_1{
   background: url(../img/img_route_walk.svg) no-repeat top left #ff0;
   background-size: contain; 
}
```

Если svg имеет прозрачный фон, он зальется.

Comment: В данном случае это не работает. SVG цвет не меняет.

Comment: @МаксимЗакшевский, вы же написали - не меняя цвета самого svg

Comment: тогда Н - никак

Comment: Извините, не совсем правильно выразился. Поменять цвет самой "картинки", но не в ней. Просто данный свг у меня на сайте будет не в одном месте, но в разных цветах, не хотелось плодить кучу файлов.

Comment: Только если вставите код картинки прямо в код страницы, таким способом - никак

Answer (score 0):

```
.form-select{
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg 
    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' 
    viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3e%3cpath fill='none' 
    stroke='rgb(54, 181, 28)' stroke-linecap='round' 
    stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='2' 
    d='M2 5l6 6 6-6'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}
```

Добавить свойтсво `stroke='rgb(54, 181, 28)'` сразу в сss или в сам svg.

Кодировка обязательно `rgb`.